# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object after adding DateTime column in ef7

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am new to asp.net mvc ef 7, trying to migrate from vb.net.

I have a class as follows

```
[Table("MatGrp")]
public class MatGrp
{
    [Key]
    public decimal Grp_RNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [Display(Name = "Group Code")]
    public string Grp_Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Group Name")]
    public string Grp_Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Cre_By { get; set; }
    public DateTime Cre_DtTm { get; set; }
    public decimal Mod_By { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public System.DateTime Mod_DtTm { get; set; }

}
```

I have generated a controller for this class, CRUD opertions work fine if I remove public System.DateTime Mod_DtTm { get; set; } column from the class, but adding this column gives a error as show in this Stack trace

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> lambda_method(Closure , ValueBuffer )
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> lambda_method(Closure , ValueBuffer )
>
> Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityLoadInfo.Materialize()
>
> Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.GetEntity(IKeyValue
>   keyValue, EntityLoadInfo entityLoadInfo, Boolean queryStateManager)
>
> Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalEntityQueryableExpressionVisitor.CreateEntity[TEntity](IQuerySource
>   querySource, ValueBuffer valueBuffer, Int32 valueBufferOffset,
>   QueryContext queryContext, IEntityType entityType, Boolean
>   trackingQuery, KeyValueFactory keyValueFactory, Func`2 materializer,
>   Boolean allowNullResult, Boolean useQueryBuffer)
>
> lambda_method(Closure , ValueBuffer )
>
> System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.b__0(TSource
>   x)
>
> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
> Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
> System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> FMWeb.Controllers.MatGrpsController.Index() in MatGrpsController.cs
>
> 22. return View(_context.MatGrp.ToList());
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(MethodInfo
>   actionMethodInfo, Object instance, Object[] orderedActionArguments)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker.d__6.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__53.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__44.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.d__6.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.Template.TemplateRoute.d__27.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.d__9.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet.ExceptionTrackingMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.d__5.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

What is going wrong?? how to analyze/debug the trace?
Thanks in advance

The Column Cre_DtTm allows null. below is the table script:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MatGrp](  [Grp_RNo] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL,  
 [Grp_Code] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,  [Grp_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Cre_By] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,  [Cre_DtTm] [datetime] NULL, 
 [Mod_By] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,  [Mod_DtTm] [datetime] NULL, 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MatGrp_Grp_RNo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ( [Grp_RNo] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =
 OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON
 [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The column allows null in table definition in the database, but it must also allow null in the class (`?` in `DateTime?` to allow null).

```
public DateTime? Cre_DtTm { get; set; }
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

check the database. If it's a NOT NULL column and you added it without using a default value it'll get all ragey

Comment: The column allows null.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MatGrp](
 [Grp_RNo] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL,
 [Grp_Code] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Grp_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Cre_By] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
 [Cre_DtTm] [datetime] NULL,
 [Mod_By] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
 [Mod_DtTm] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MatGrp_Grp_RNo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Grp_RNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]